# How does my program compile in command line with this format?

Tags: java, command-line

I never did this before but the program is supposed to compile with this expression:

`%java myProgram [input file]`

I'm using the File and scanner objects to parse through a .java or .txt input file.

Comment: Don't you mean `javac` rather than `java`?

Comment: My assignment says %java, but I'm more concerned about how to make my program run from giving the file directory for input file in the brackets. I'm assuming args from `main(String[] args)` accomplishes this.

Comment: OK, it seems you're concerned about running the program, not compiling it. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one or more `.java` files and want to run your program on the command line, there are two steps to doing that.

1. Compile your program. You use `javac` for that task. A full description can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), but in most cases you'll want to do something like this:

   ```
   javac MyProgram1.java PartOfMyProgram.java OtherPartOfMyProgram.java
   ```
2. Run your program. You'll uye the `java` command line tool for that. Again, a full description can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) but you'll probably want to do something like this:

   ```
   java MyProgram1.java "Hello World" 3
   ```

   The `"Hello World" 3` part of that are arguments you are passing to the program and they will be available as `args[0]` and `args[1]` respectively in the `main` method.

If you want to find out more about command line arguments, I'd recommend reading [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html). Basically however, those input files you seem to want to pass to the program will be available as elements of the `args`-array in the main method.